# Adding Google tag manager to Magnolia CMS

Tags: java, google-tag-manager, magnolia

I have a site built using Magnolia CMS, and I need to add Google Tag manager to one page. I've code and i need to add it to the page , so just i need help how i could add this code to Magnolia page:

```html
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i)
Unknown macro:
Unknown macro: {w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push( Unknown macro}
);var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-KFVHMZ5');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
Additionally, paste this code immediately after the opening <body> tag:
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KFVHMZ5"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Use [Marketing Tags module](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS62/Marketing+Tags+module). That's the simplest solution. Alternatively you can add it to all page templates and manage by yourself, but I wouldn't do that.